# Restricting application components access for a particular user angular2

Tags: angular, authentication

How to restrict access for a particular user in angular2. I have an application where a super user logs into the application. But the same application when accessed by a different user, it has to be disabled. Can someone please tell me how to achieve that

Comment: use auth guard to check whether that user have access to that component

Comment: LoggedIn(){

   const timeOutTIme =  AppSettings.sessionTimeOut * 60 * 1000; /* ms */
    can I add users as parameters here?
   let lastActiveDateTime:Date = new Date(sessionStorage.getItem('lastActiveDateTime'));
   let idleTime:number = new Date().getTime() - lastActiveDateTime.getTime();
   if(idleTime < timeOutTIme && sessionStorage.getItem('token') != null){
     sessionStorage.setItem('lastActiveDateTime',new Date().toString());

     return true;
   }
    return false;
  } Can i add users as parameters in the above code and restrict on the basis of who logs in?

Comment: And use these for restriction while passing

Comment: can you formate your code and update it in the question so that t will be readable